# How to reroute faces in blender 2.79 what is (ctrl a) shortcut stands for?

Tags: modeling

do you know about rerouting faces in blender by pressing (crtl+a)can change faces route to form or change face shape, it joins or rotate faces to form a face as required by artist
i have an video link the guy is doing it by pressing (CONTROL A) i cant do it please help please follow the link below to know what i want...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Lu-n5cd6y8&t=244s

Answer (score 2):

It's more precisely at 3m50s: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Lu-n5cd6y8&t=3m50s

It looks like he has created his own shortcut, he's rotating the edge with the *Mesh* > *Edges* > ***Rotate Edge*** function, but you can simply access with a <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: That's what I thought at first too, but if you look more closely I don't think that's it. Look at the two verts where the edge was before rotation. It's like they bow out. Maybe Edge Rotate + Smooth?

Comment: it's because he has a Subsurf with Adjust Edit Cage option enabled